# emacs info mode: back to previous page

Tags: emacs

In Emacs info mode, it is possible to press `RET` on a hyperlink to follow it. However, is it possible to return to the previous page after opening the link? Also, is it possible to open the link in a new buffer (other than the default `*info*`)?

Note that I use the command line, so any GUI feature won't work.

Comment: I found it in the help of `Info-mode`. `l`: Move back in history to the last node you were at.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you found yourself, type `l` to return to the previous page.

You can open a link in a new buffer by using a prefix argument: `C-u RET` instead of just `RET`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is just an `evil-mode` feature, but because `l` is bound to move the cursor to the right one character one cannot use it to move back in `*info*`, but it seems that `C-o` works to take you to the previous `*info*` page.

If you get desperate, one can also run `M-x Info-history-back` as well.

Comment: I am running spacemacs evil mode, and C-o was not very discoverable for me - thank you!